# Can I point to 2 different Django apps to 2 different urls?

Tags: django

I have a domain named xyz.com running a django project with a database. I have another Django project which should point to xyz.com/pray with a different database. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: This is Apache config (or IIS) - suggest you ask on ServerFault.

Comment: *Try it*. If you run into problems, *then* ask a question here about that *specific* problem. Asking if something is possible is just wasting your time and ours.

Answer (score 2):

yes, 2 things i would look at:

1. a db router for one of your applications
2. a urls.py files for each of your apps

project/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^pray/', include('prayapp.urls')), # all of this apps ulrs start with /pray
    url(r'^', include('otherapp.urls')), # all of these urls start at the root /
    ...
)
```

and from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example:

db settings:

```
DATABASES = {
# for the rest of your project
'default': {
    'NAME': 'app_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'USER': 'postgres_user',
    'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
},
# for your prayapp
'other': {
    'NAME': 'user_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'USER': 'mysql_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
}
}
```

Custom router:

```
class PrayAppRouter(object):
    """A router to control all database operations on models in
    the prayapp application"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on prayapp models to 'other'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'prayapp':
            return 'other'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on prayapp models to 'other'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'prayapp':
            return 'other'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        "Allow any relation if a model in prayapp is involved"
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'prayapp' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'prayapp':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        "Make sure the prayapp app only appears on the 'other' db"
        if db == 'other':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'prayapp'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'prayapp':
            return False
        return None
```

add this to your settings.py

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.PrayAppRouter',]
```